# Github problema de Autenticacion

Tags: git, github

Recien inicio con Linux, necesito instalar un proyecto de la empresa en linux, y cada vez que lo intento me da este error:

```
Password for 'https://NombredeUsuario@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/empresa/repo.git/'
```

No se que pueda ser, estoy en ceros.

Comment: Debes configurar tu usuario y contraseña, echa un [vistazo](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Inicio---Sobre-el-Control-de-Versiones-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez) , debes poner tu correo con el que estas registrado en gitlab o github

Comment: user.email=usuario@empresa.com
user.name=Usuario
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true

Me ha quedado asi